# How to use the same database tables inside each module when creating independent routes from each other

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I want to create a microservice application where each mouth would be unique and use schemas models and services inside its folder

This is what my file system looks like, I have removed modules and folders that are not relevant to the question.

```
│   config.ini
│   main.py
│   start_consumer.py
│   __init__.py
│      
│
│
├───depends
│       captcha.py
│       schemas_validators.py
│
├───exceptions
│       custom_exception.py
│       __init__.py
│
│
├───routs
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
│   ├───account
│   │       controller.py
│   │       models.py
│   │       schemas.py
│   │       service.py
│   │
│   ├───auth
│   │       controller.py
│   │       models.py
│   │       schemas.py
│   │       service.py
```

And so.
in general, I have two routers (auth and account) where I use the same tables in the database.

auth/models.py

```
class User(base):
    __tablename__ = 'user_table'
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
    id: Mapped[UUID] = mapped_column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True,
                                     default=uuid,
                                     server_default=func.gen_random_uuid())
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(90))
    secondname: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(90))
    lastname: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(90))
    phone : Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(30), unique=True)
    language : Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(2))
    gender: Mapped[GenderEnum] = mapped_column(Enum(GenderEnum, name='gender'), unique=False, nullable=True)

    credentials: Mapped[Optional["Credentials"]] = relationship(back_populates="user")
    user_dates: Mapped[Optional["UserDates"]] = relationship(back_populates="user")
    verification_user: Mapped[Optional["VerificationUser"]] = relationship(back_populates="user")

class UserDates(base):
    __tablename__ = 'user_dates_table'
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
    id: Mapped[UUID] = mapped_column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True,
                                     default=uuid,
                                     server_default=func.gen_random_uuid())
    birthdate: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(20), nullable=True)
    created_at: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(20), nullable=False)
    deleted_at: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(20), nullable=True)
    user_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("user_table.id"))

    user: Mapped[Optional["User"]] = relationship(back_populates="user_dates")

class Credentials(base):
    __tablename__ = 'credentials_table'
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
    id: Mapped[UUID] = mapped_column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True,
                                     default=uuid,
                                     server_default=func.gen_random_uuid())
    login: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(90), unique=False)
    tg_id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(40), nullable=True)
    password: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(120), nullable=False)
    user_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("user_table.id"))

    user: Mapped[Optional["User"]] = relationship(back_populates="credentials")

class VerificationUser(base):
    __tablename__ = 'verification_user_table'
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
    id: Mapped[UUID] = mapped_column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True,
                                     default=uuid,
                                     server_default=func.gen_random_uuid())
    email_verification: Mapped[bool] = mapped_column(Boolean, default=False)
    tg_verification: Mapped[bool] = mapped_column(Boolean, default=False)
    user_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("user_table.id"))

    user: Mapped[Optional["User"]] = relationship(back_populates="verification_user")
```

account/models.py

```
class GenderEnum(str, enum.Enum):
    MALE = 'male'
    FEMALE = 'female'

class User(base):
    __tablename__ = 'user_table'
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
    id: Mapped[UUID] = mapped_column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True,
                                     default=uuid,
                                     server_default=func.gen_random_uuid())
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(90))
    secondname: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(90))
    lastname: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(90))
    phone : Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(30), unique=True)
    language : Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(2))
    gender: Mapped[GenderEnum] = mapped_column(Enum(GenderEnum, name='gender'), unique=False, nullable=True)

    credentials: Mapped[Optional["Credentials"]] = relationship(back_populates="user")
    user_dates: Mapped[Optional["UserDates"]] = relationship(back_populates="user")
    verification_user: Mapped[Optional["VerificationUser"]] = relationship(back_populates="user")

class UserDates(base):
    __tablename__ = 'user_dates_table'
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
    id: Mapped[UUID] = mapped_column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True,
                                     default=uuid,
                                     server_default=func.gen_random_uuid())
    birthdate: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(20), nullable=True)
    created_at: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(20), nullable=False)
    deleted_at: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(20), nullable=True)
    user_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("user_table.id"))

    user: Mapped[Optional["User"]] = relationship(back_populates="user_dates")

class Credentials(base):
    __tablename__ = 'credentials_table'
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
    id: Mapped[UUID] = mapped_column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True,
                                     default=uuid,
                                     server_default=func.gen_random_uuid())
    login: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(90), unique=False)
    tg_id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(40), nullable=True)
    password: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(120), nullable=False)
    user_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("user_table.id"))

    user: Mapped[Optional["User"]] = relationship(back_populates="credentials")

class VerificationUser(base):
    __tablename__ = 'verification_user_table'
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
    id: Mapped[UUID] = mapped_column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True,
                                     default=uuid,
                                     server_default=func.gen_random_uuid())
    email_verification: Mapped[bool] = mapped_column(Boolean, default=False)
    tg_verification: Mapped[bool] = mapped_column(Boolean, default=False)
    user_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("user_table.id"))

    user: Mapped[Optional["User"]] = relationship(back_populates="verification_user")
```

In these routers, I'm using exactly the same tables.

in Auth to create an account and log in to it as well as for jwt

in Account to display data on the page and to change your records.

I've already tried a lot of things, but I still don't understand how to do it all right

I get errors like this:

1)Multiple classes found for path "Credentials" in the registry of this declarative base. Please use a fully module-qualified path.

if I rename them then I can't get any object from the database
2)cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object

What could this be related to ?